# Laravel Nova remove resources from navigation

Tags: laravel-nova

Perhaps someone has already encountered a similar problem and can tell me.

How to delete “resources” item in navigation. Not a separate resource - but in general, completely remove the entire list, including the title.

Screenshot: https://prnt.sc/lw1nup

Need to: https://prnt.sc/lw1xf9

What I was trying to do:

- I tried to comment out the entire contents of the views / resources /
  navigation.blade.php file
- I tried to comment out the new line calling "new ResourceManager" inside
  registerTools in src / NovaServiceProvider.php.

So far, all without results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of v1.2.0 there is a function `availableForNavigation` in `Laravel\Nova\Resource` which returns true.

You can override that function to return false in `App\Nova\Resource` abstract class.

```
/**
 * Determine if this resource is available for navigation.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return bool
 */
public static function availableForNavigation(Request $request)
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: it will only hide a separate resource, but not the entire list, including the title, the one in the screenshot

Comment: @AndreyMarkov `$displayInNavigation` attribute in each resources hide specific resource. But the one mentioned in the answer is `availableForNavigation` function under `App\Nova\Resource` which will hide the all resources including the title. It works for me

Answer (score 7):

Another way to hide a resource from resource list is by adding the below code in your resource file:

```
public static $displayInNavigation = false;
```

That I wish we had it in the document as well.